# Blackberry twitter api me showing unwanted characters

Tags: blackberry, twitter

I am using twitter api me 1.8 in my blackberry application.
But in the login page it is showing unwanted box-like characters.

How can I fix this?

Comment: try to connect with BIS. its not unwanted characters. the language is hindi. thats why its showing like that.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using browser content manager for login in.
Use `BrowserFieldOAuthDialogWrapper` instead of `BrowserContentManagerOAuthDialogWrapper`.